# How to set array of values to state and fetch during submit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Depending on the count, the number of text box will be generated.
When I try to set the text box value to the state, textbox is not accepting more than one value.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [option, setOption] = useState([]);

  const Generator = (count) => {
    let textArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count.count; i++) {
      let name = "txt" + i;
      textArr.push(<input type="text" key= {name} id={name} onChange={e => onChangeOptions(e,i)} value={getOptionValue(i)}/>);
    }
    return textArr;
  };

  const getOptionValue = (i) => {
    let opt = [...option];
    return opt[i];
  }

  const onChangeOptions = (e,i) => {
    let val = e.target.value;
    let opt = [...option];
    opt[i] = val;
    setOption(opt);
    console.log(opt);
  }

  const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    console.log(option);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="count"
        onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <Generator count={count} />
      <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Generator` is defined inside your component, so it's a different function on each render. React thinks a different element is being rendered each time, which makes the input lose focus. Instead, directly create the array of inputs in the JSX with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
{
  [...Array(+count)].map((_, i) => (
    <input type="text" key={"txt" + i} id={"txt" + i} onChange={e => onChangeOptions(e,i)} value={getOptionValue(i)}/>
  ))
}
```

Alternatively, extract `Generator` into a separate component. Do not define it inside another component.